# Is not valid win32 application

Tags: c++, c

В общем когда запуская приложение высвечивается ошибка "is not valid win32 application". На просторах интернета ответов не нашёл по этому обращаюсь сюда.

Файл: Windows Desktop Wizard (dynamic lib)
IDE: VS 2017

Code:
Header.h:

```
#pragma once
bool isPrime(unsigned p);
int getQ();
int getP(int q);
int getPhi(int q, int p);
int getE();
int getD(int phi, int E);
```

Source.cpp:

```
#include "Header.h"    
#include "stdio.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "locale.h"    
#include "math.h"
#include "cstdlib"

int main()
{
    int q = getQ();
    int p = getP(q);
    int phi = getPhi(q, p);
    int E = getE();
    int D = getD(phi, E);

    printf("%d", q);
    printf("%d", p);
    printf("%d", phi);
    printf("%d", E);
    printf("%d", D);
}
```

Functions.cpp:

```
#include "Header.h"

#include "stdio.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "locale.h"

#include "math.h"
#include "cstdlib"



static bool isPrime(unsigned p) {

    if (p < 2) return false;
    if (p == 2) return true;
    if (p % 2 == 0) return false;

    for (unsigned i = 3; i <= sqrt(p); i += 2) {
        if ((p % i) == 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int getQ() {
    int q = rand();
    while (!isPrime(q) || q < 100) {
        q = rand();
    }
    return q;
}

int getP(int q) {
    int p = rand();
    while (!isPrime(p) || q == p || p < 100) {
        p = rand();
    }
    return p;
}

int getPhi(int q, int p) {
    return (p - 1)*(q - 1);
}

int getE() {
    return 17;
}

int getD(int phi, int E) {
    return (1 % phi) / E;
}
```

Comment: Подозрение, что вы создаете что-то не то. Типа 64-разрядного приложения, которое пытаетесь запустить в 32-разрядной операционной системе... Какая у вас операционка и какое приложение создается?

Comment: операционка х64, создаю приложение Windows Desktop Wizard (dll, empty project), в configuration manager стоит x86

Comment: Если это dll, то что ж вы пытаетесь запускать ее как приложение?

Comment: То есть я никак не могу проверить работоспособность функций в файле Source.cpp? Как тогда правильно запустить?

Comment: Пишите еще просто программу, которая будет вызывать экспортируемые из DLL функции

Comment: Измените тип проекта на `Application (exe)` в свойствах проекта.

Comment: Только ваш код не очень похож на код динамической библиотеки. Возможно, вам не нужна DLL, а просто Win32 Console Application

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить код, что бы был похож на динамическую библеотеку

Comment: То есть что бы подключить данную библиотеку необходимо создать ещё один проект? Создал windows console application, прописал #include "library1" (имя файла dll), пишет cannot open source file

Comment: Написать `.def` файл для экспорта функций, удалить `Source.cpp`... Хмм, вам явно стоит ознакомиться с основами c++, в т.ч. с работой препроцессора, с использованием директивы `include`

Comment: Если это dll - то перед каждой функцией ещё добавить `__declspec(dllexport)`. Лучше в прототипе. Вот как то так -  `__declspec(dllexport) int getP(int q);`. Для красоты ещё делают макрос - `#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)`. И что за компилятор?